# Windows Installer project is unsupported in Visual Studio 11 BETA

Tags: windows-services, visual-studio-2012

It says that my windows installer project is unsupported. "ProjectType" = "8:{978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA}" is in vdproj file. Can i work with it in VS11 beta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still use Windows Service project. It is *installer* that is not supported by VS11. Accoring to [Visual Studio team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx), old VS Install and Deploy projects (*.vdproj) will not be supported in any future releases starting with VS11. Migrate to WIX.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I'll change question a bit to help people searching for it.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue with trying to open a installer package sent to me via another developer, apparently I needed to install the appropriate version of (in Visual Studio):

> [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)

To open this type of project. Once I did that I was able to open this project type.